# What is 'OE Gloss.'?

Tags: english, etymology, reference-request

I'm not a linguistics student, so my bad if this is actually very obvious/can be found online (I tried. Really.), but what is, exactly, the OE Gloss.?

All I could find is that it means *Old English Glossary*, and even that was just me guessing. I've been guessing that it's a book, and so I tried Googling as though it was. Before that, I just tried the abbreviation (as that's how it was in the OED website), and then I tried the name without any kind of abbreviation, then etc.

I'm not sure if this part is important, but basically, I have a short etymology paper to write and one of the sources of the first attestation of the word is this. The OE Gloss. And I have to write a few sentences about it, so I do have to do some research on it, though I can't find anything at all. At least, I don't think I'm finding the correct information. And to add to that, I'm not even a hundred percent sure if the OE Gloss. is the actual source. Even though I've been told by my professor that it is. Here is the extract from the OED website:

*OE. Gloss.* in Haupt *Zeitschrift*

To me, it sounds that the source is this Zeitschrift book. Or perhaps that's me just hoping it is, because I found information on Zeitschrift, and nothing on *OE. Gloss.*

Can anyone please help? And apologies if this isn't the right stack exchange - it's my first time posting anything on this website.

Comment: My understanding is that your guess is correct that it's referring to the Old English glossary in the Haupt Zeitschrift (or magazine). I presume the magazine in question to be [the one discussed here in WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitschrift_für_deutsches_Altertum_und_deutsche_Literatur)

Comment: Can you give a link to the "OED website" you found the extract from?

Comment: @Taegyung I don't want to post the link, as it contains my university details (and I don't know how to post the link without posting those). But you can go to www.oed.com and search for the word 'ladle', click on the noun, and the extract I posted should be there near the top.

Comment: The whole entry looks very weird. German *Zeitschrift* just means "journal". Without being specific we don't know which one. *Hauptzeitschrift* is an actually used German compound meaning "main journal" contrasting *Beilage* "supplement". I think the entry is messed up beyond recognition, though @GastonÜmlaut's guess might be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the source given by @Gaston Ümlaut in a comment. The *Zeitschrift für deutsches Alterthum* is available in digitised form and [here is the relevant table of contents](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PID=PPN345204107_0009). Note that the original title is *Angelsächsische glossen* and the author is *Bouterwek*.

Comment: Specifically (if my German is not too rusty, but corrections are welcome) - these are the Anglo-Saxon / Old English glosses of Latin words in [Aldhelm's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldhelm) _De Virginitate_ as found in the Brussels manuscript (?).

Comment: Moriz Haupt was the editor of the "Zeitschrift für deutsches Alterthum". His surname happens to mean "head, main". There is no "main journal". The mind boggles.